GNU Assembly Printing Formatted Error Messages - macro substitution into quoted string for .print
I have a setup like this:
.set ERRORS, 1
.macro ERROR_SUMMARY, COUNT
    .print "\e[1;92mZ#\e[1;31m Compilation Failed with \\COUNT Error(s)\e[0m!"
.endm

ERROR_SUMMARY ERRORS

This should print:
Compilation Failed with 1 Error(s).
However, instead of printing Compilation Failed with 1 Error(s) it will print Compilation Failed with ERRORS Error(s).

You may need to use .altmacro mode with the %expr syntax to make this work.

You can do it in .altmacro mode and a helper macro:
.altmacro
.set ERRORS, 1
.macro ERROR_PRINT, COUNT
    .print "\e[1;92mZ#\e[1;31m Compilation Failed with \COUNT Error(s)\e[0m!"
.endm
.macro ERROR_SUMMARY, COUNT
    ERROR_PRINT %\COUNT
.endm

ERROR_SUMMARY ERRORS

(Mind the single backslash in the .print)
Of course if you are happy with adding the % to the invocation as ERROR_SUMMARY %ERRORS then you don't need the helper.

Although this didn't work right out of the box, I got it working for my setup.
